# Google Places + Map code updating from v1 to v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I followed a tutorial from;
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

The google places aspect works perfect but the google map code is outdated. Im not sure how to update google map code from v1 to v2?
Any pointers??

```
public class PlacesMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    // Nearest places
    PlacesList nearPlaces;

    // Map view
    MapView mapView;

    // Map overlay items
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    // Map controllers
    MapController mc;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    OverlayItem overlayitem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_places);

        // Getting intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Users current geo location
        String user_latitude = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
        String user_longitude = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");

        // Nearplaces list
        nearPlaces = (PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("near_places");

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // Geopoint to place on map
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude) * 1E6),
                (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude) * 1E6));

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable_user = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user, this);

        // Map overlay item
        overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
                "That is you!");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        mc = mapView.getController();

        // These values are used to get map boundary area
        // The area where you can see all the markers on screen
        int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // check for null in case it is null
        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
            // loop through all the places
            for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {
                latitude = place.geometry.location.lat; // latitude
                longitude = place.geometry.location.lng; // longitude

                // Geopoint to place on map
                geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                        (int) (longitude * 1E6));

                // Map overlay item
                overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, place.name,
                        place.vicinity);

                itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);


                // calculating map boundary area
                minLat  = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
                minLong = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
                maxLat  = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
                maxLong = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
            }
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            // showing all overlay items
            itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
        }

        // Adjusting the zoom level so that you can see all the markers on map
        mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));

        // Showing the center of the map
        mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
        mapView.postInvalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

       private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

       private Context context;

       public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
       }

       public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
            this(defaultMarker);
            this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
       {   

           if (event.getAction() == 1) {
               GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                   (int) event.getX(),
                   (int) event.getY());
               // latitude
               double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
               // longitude
               double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
               //Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           return false;
       } 

       @Override
       protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
          return mapOverlays.get(i);
       }

       @Override
       public int size() {
          return mapOverlays.size();
       }

       @Override
       protected boolean onTap(int index) {
         OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
         AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
         dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
         dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
         dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
         dialog.show();
         return true;
       }

       public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
          mapOverlays.add(overlay);
       }

       public void populateNow(){
           this.populate();
       }
 }
```

---

```
public class NearbyActivity extends Activity{
    // flag for Internet connection status
        Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

        // Connection detector class
        ConnectionDetector cd;

        // Alert Dialog Manager
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

        // Google Places
        GooglePlaces googlePlaces;

        // Places List
        PlacesList nearPlaces;

        // GPS Location
        GPSTracker gps;

        // Button
        Button btnShowOnMap;

        // Progress dialog
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Places Listview
        ListView lv;

        // ListItems data
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


        // KEY Strings
        public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference"; // id of the place
        public static String KEY_NAME = "name"; // name of the place
        public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vicinity"; // Place area name




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);  
        Button buttonNear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNearby);       
        buttonNear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent HomeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class); 
                startActivity(HomeScreen);
            }
            }); 




                        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

                        // Check if Internet present
                        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                        if (!isInternetPresent) {
                            // Internet Connection is not present
                            alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                            // stop executing code by return
                            return;
                        }

                        // creating GPS Class object
                        gps = new GPSTracker(this);

                        // check if GPS location can get
                        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                            Log.d("Your Location", "latitude:" + gps.getLatitude() + ", longitude: " + gps.getLongitude());
                        } else {
                            // Can't get user's current location
                            alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyActivity.this, "GPS Status",
                                    "Couldn't get location information. Please enable GPS",
                                    false);
                            // stop executing code by return
                            return;
                        }

                        // Getting listview
                        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

                        // button show on map
                        btnShowOnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_map);

                        // calling background Async task to load Google Places
                        // After getting places from Google all the data is shown in listview
                        new LoadPlaces().execute();

                        /** Button click event for shown on map */
                        btnShowOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                        PlacesMapActivity.class);
                                // Sending user current geo location
                                i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
                                i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));

                                // passing near places to map activity
                                i.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
                                // staring activity
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });


                        /**
                         * ListItem click event
                         * On selecting a listitem SinglePlaceActivity is launched
                         * */
                        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                                // getting values from selected ListItem
                                String reference = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reference)).getText().toString();

                                // Starting new intent
                                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                        SinglePlaceActivity.class);

                                // Sending place refrence id to single place activity
                                // place refrence id used to get "Place full details"
                                in.putExtra(KEY_REFERENCE, reference);
                                startActivity(in);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    /**
                     * Background Async Task to Load Google places
                     * */
                    class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                        /**
                         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                         * */
                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NearbyActivity.this);
                            pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading Places..."));
                            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                            pDialog.show();
                        }

                        /**
                         * getting Places JSON
                         * */
                        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                            // creating Places class object
                            googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

                            try {
                                // Separeate your place types by PIPE symbol "|"
                                // If you want all types places make it as null
                                // Check list of types supported by google
                                // 
                                String types = null; // Listing places only cafes, restaurants

                                // Radius in meters - increase this value if you don't find any places
                                double radius = 400; // 1000 meters 

                                // get nearest places
                                nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(),
                                        gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        /**
                         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                         * and show the data in UI
                         * Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI from background
                         * thread, otherwise you will get error
                         * **/
                        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            // updating UI from Background Thread
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    /**
                                     * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                                     * */
                                    // Get json response status
                                    String status = nearPlaces.status;

                                    // Check for all possible status
                                    if(status.equals("OK")){
                                        // Successfully got places details
                                        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                                            // loop through each place
                                            for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                                // Place reference won't display in listview - it will be hidden
                                                // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                                                map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                                                // Place name
                                                map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);


                                                // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                                                placesListItems.add(map);
                                            }
                                            // list adapter
                                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(NearbyActivity.this, placesListItems,
                                                    R.layout.list_item,
                                                    new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                                                            R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                                            // Adding data into listview
                                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                                        // Zero results found
                                        alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyActivity.this, "Near Places",
                                                "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                                                false);
                                    }
                                    else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                                    {
                                        alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                                "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                                                false);
                                    }
                                    else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                                    {
                                        alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                                "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                                                false);
                                    }
                                    else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                                    {
                                        alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                                "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                                                false);
                                    }
                                    else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                                    {
                                        alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                                "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                                                false);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                                "Sorry error occured.",
                                                false);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
                        return true;
                    }

}
```

Comment: You can read from the developers page - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: just follow the documentation of the V2. V2 is 100% easier to implement than V1. Remove MapActivity as you don't need those anymore, now everything can be done with fragment.

Comment: v2 is completely rewritten. You should the the same. Like Budius said it is a lot more easier than v1.

Comment: The app im working on already uses google map v2 api, this new map is being created in a different activity. I assume its possible to use just the one mapfragment??

Comment: hay joseph kenny is u r problem solved?

Comment: Yes problem solved. Il be getting rid of google maps api, using osm instead